# How to pass var from jsx to pure css file in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, var

I want to pass var form parent component to child component (--my-custom) that will set color for child component , but when i write like this it gives me error , if you see i use my custom variable in MyButton.css in this manner it will adjust my button to any color i want.

// my jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles/MyButton.css";

const MyButton = ({ title, handelClick, color }) => {
  
  return (
    <div class="parentbutton">
      <a class="mybutton" onClick={() => handelClick()} style={{ --my-custom: color }}>
        <span>{title}</span>
        <i></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyButton;
```

//MyButton.css

```
a.mybutton:hover {
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  background-color: var(--my-custom);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em var(--my-custom);
  color: var(--my-custom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your style like this, it might works!

```
<div style={{ "--my-css-var": 10 } as React.CSSProperties} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `inline styling` without a `.css` file

```js
import React from "react";

const MyButton = ({ title, handelClick, color }) => {

    return (
        <div className="parentbutton">
            <a className="mybutton" onClick={() => handelClick()} style={{
                backgroundColor: color,
                boxShadow: `0 0 2.5em ${color}`,
                color: color
            }}>
                <span>{title}</span>
                <i></i>
            </a>
        </div >
    );
};

export default MyButton;
```